# Get value of media query using Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries

Is there a way to get the value inside of a media query using jquery?

Example:

```
@media(max-width:767px) { .story {color: black} }
```

Using jquery get the value inside the parens:

```
max-width:767
```

Comment: Firstly you cannot have jQuery inside CSS. What are you trying to achieve? Please add some code snippet and explain your issues.

Comment: I know I can't do that. It's not what I am asking.  I don't have any code snippets I am trying to wrap my head around if this is even possible.  Similar to how you can get the value attributes of a class element using jquery, I am trying to get the value of what is inside the parenthesis of the media query.  ie: `var media = 'max-width:767';` from the css `@media(max-width:767px) { .story {color: black} }`

Comment: jQuery works with elements in the DOM. You cannot use it get values from CSS. If you want to get the current width of window then it's possible. var max = $(document).width();

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I am always surprised by with what some people come up with.

Answer (score 4):

You can iterate `document.styleSheets`, check if `.cssRules` or `.rules` rule of stylesheet is `instanceof` `CSSMediaRule`, if true, iterate `CSSMediaRule` `.cssRules` to get `.cssText` of `CSSMediaRule`.

```css
@media(max-width:767px) {
  .story {
    color: black
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="story">span</span>
<script>
  for (let sheet of document.styleSheets) {
    for (let rule of (sheet.cssRules || sheet.rules)) {
      if (rule instanceof CSSMediaRule) {
        cssmedia: for (let prop of rule.cssRules) {
          let mediarules = prop.parentRule.media;
           for (let i = 0; i < mediarules.length; i++) {            
            if (mediarules[i] === "(max-width: 767px)") {
               document.querySelector(prop.selectorText)
               .textContent = prop.cssText;
               break cssmedia;
             }       
           }
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

If you are trying to listen for changes to media query you can use `window.matchMedia()`, `.addListener()`; see [Testing media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Testing_media_queries)

```
  var mql = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 767px)");
  mql.addListener(query)
  query(mql)
  function query(mediaquery) {
    console.log(mediaquery);
    if (mediaquery.matches) {
      // media query matches
    } else {
      // media query does not match
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

The measuring the screen width on resize of the window, I check for a css rule that is changed by the media query. This way, regardless of the how the browser treats the scrollbar, the media query will fire at the same time.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    checkSize();

    $(window).resize(checkSize);
});

function checkSize(){
    if ($(".sampleClass").css("float") == "none" ){

    }
}
```